# Mule ESB doesn't run the second time after the first time

Tags: mule, esb, aggregator

I guess that the problem may be the 'MULE_CORRELATION_ID'. I use the  tag to deal a batch of datas. the configuration as follows:

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="dataSource" pollingFrequency="2000" queryTimeout="-1" transactionPerMessage="false" resultSetHandler-ref="resutSetHandler" doc:name="Database"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="read" value="SELECT 1 as CID, A.* from ewell_login_user A"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>
<file:connector name="output" outputAppend="true" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].txt" doc:name="File"></file:connector>
<flow name="zhicall-zhongshan" doc:name="zhicall-zhongshan">
    <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint queryKey="read" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Database">
    </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
    <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties" >
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="10"/>
        <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="10000"/>
    </message-properties-transformer>
    <collection-aggregator timeout="5000" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
    <custom-transformer encoding="UTF-8" class="com.zhicall.esb.transformer.TestTransFormer" doc:name="Java"/>
    <stdio:outbound-endpoint doc:name="STDIO" responseTimeout="10000" system="OUT" encoding="UTF-8"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2):

MULE_CORRELATION_ID must be unique for each group of messages. 
You shouldn't be setting it and if you do, you need to make sure that you use a different id for each group.

Comment: If I comment the MULE_CORRELATION_ID out, the MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE doesn't take effect cause the transformer deal one record one time. So how should I modify the configuration? Thks!

Comment: To make sure that every group-id is unique, I set the value of MULE_CORRELATION_ID to the expression '#[function:datestamp]'. This time the app runs time after time, but another question occurs which quite confuses me. The question is that the MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE seems to doesn't take effect every time.  Sometimes the group size is smaller than 10. And sometimes the app throws a exception. And more than one group of data would be polled at one time.